# Question about voltage ratings on constant current LED Drivers

Tags: voltage-regulator, switch-mode-power-supply, constant-current, led-driver

I have a 50W LED chip, 28-32V, 1400mA max current.

I'm looking at a 60W, [1400mA constant current LED Driver](http://www.mouser.co.il/ProductDetail/Mean-Well/PCD-60-1400B/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMvV8Y9YugmIguAUY71TS%2FYq%2FSRwfzziauMWbv2IHjX3mg%3D%3D) but it's output voltage is rated 25V to 43V.

Will this driver work as is, or do I need to limit the voltage of the output so it falls within the LED's range?

Comment: Nope, you are good to go. Google 'compliance voltage' to read up more on the process behind this phenomenon.

Answer (score 4):

The LED itself will limit the voltage when the 1.4A flows through it. That voltage will be somewhere between 28V and 32V.

It is only important that the *possible range* of LED array forward voltages (as measured at the operating current) is contained entirely within the range of permissible output voltages of the driver.

Of course you will need an adequate heat sink for the 40W or so maximum power that the array will have to dissipate.

Comment: ... and that heat sink is actually why I still haven't built a permanently useful lamp out of the ten 30W white LED modules I've got lying around – got the const-current step up converter designed, PCB delivered, assembled, got things measured with a dummy load, but short of spending serious money on active cooling, I can't seem to make the leads not solder themselves off the LED in operation :/

Comment: So, in other words, it will work without additional voltage regulation?

It will be water cooled

Comment: @SlartyBartfast Yes. It's analogous to plugging something into a constant voltage supply- the load will take what current it needs, and provided the CV supply is within high/low current limits it is fine. If it isn't, then a fuse might blow or the voltage might go wonky with too light a load. With a constant current supply, the load will take what **voltage** it needs to pass that current and provided the CC supply is within high/low voltage limits it is fine.

Answer (score 0):

The supply you chose has a wider control range than you need to regulate the current needed. If it were less, then it may not be able to reach the voltage that results from current limiting.

I use a scrap CPU heatsink with small fan for the 100W LED's I have and operates ok with care on the surface prep and clamp force.  It projects over 10k lumens of white light. Liquid CPU coolers are preferred for 100W and depends on your heat flux density. This one is the size of a silver dollar.